# Activiti Examples for Version 6 (OSGI integration needed)

Tags: activiti

Are there any example Java projects specifically for version 6?

SG

Looking a DemoApplication.java for version 7.0.

References ...

import org.activiti.api.process.model.ProcessDefinition;

... which does not appear in the version 6.0 jars at

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/activiti/

Why am I using version 6.0, because we use OSGI and only version 6 has the right exports.

Unless someone can help me with OSGI integration with version 7.0

SG